# Passing props to `Image` only when they are not undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mdxjs

I'm building a blog site with MDX & NextJS. I'm defining a custom image component that will make use of the Next `<Image>` component. The issue I'm having is relatively small, but I've been struggling to find an answer to it.

**The basic question is**: If I have a variable of `string | undefined`, is there any way in React to only pass that variable to an optional prop if it's defined? I'm pretty new to React, so this might be something super basic.

My reasoning for needing this is that the custom MDX image component should take `ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>` as props. All of these props are defined as `someType | undefined`, which makes sense since HTML attributes are optional.

My issue comes in passing these props down to Next image. How do I pass the optional `src`, `alt`, `width`, and `height` props when they are defined in the original image but not when they aren't?

The specific error I'm getting is `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | StaticImport'`, which makes perfect sense.

I tried something like this:

```js
    const src = props.src != undefined ? props.src : "";
    const alt = props.alt != undefined ? props.alt : "";
    const width = props.width != undefined ? props.width : "";
    const height = props.height != undefined ? props.height : "";
```

which was ugly, and also didn't really solve my problem. I don't want to be passing width when its undefined for example.

Comment: Have you run into a problem just passing them on even if they're `undefined`? In most cases, code dealing with optional props won't differentiate between a prop with the value `undefined` and a prop that's missing. (There *is* a difference, and it *can* be detected, but usually people don't write code to do so.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unfortunately I have. That throws `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | StaticImport'.` I could just drop out of Typescript for this one thing, which might be the best solution in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the properties you need to supply defaults for instead of `undefined`, you use *nullish coalescing*, like this:

```typescript
export function ImageWrapper(props: ImageWrapperProps) {
    return <Image
        {...props}
        src={props.src ?? ValidDefaultSrc}
        alt={props.alt ?? ValidDefaultAlt}
    />;
}
```

The order is important there, first you spread out all of the properties from `props`, then override `src` and `alt` with versions with defaults. Those are the only two required properties in the props for the Next `Image` component.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOASRBQHMk5tcCA7JADxgHpQTJGXLk+fOAFkAnnEYBXJAGclcFPCW4WYHGFWZocGAAsWg5nADuUFGDBIocNLkhcO8Su4eZ0LekIB1GzsHAAVdVQBvcjhYuCUoNAB+AC54mChgDkY4AB84eQ4AEyRMLKQiiji1ABsYVPTM7LyC4tLyypi4y2AikwaOeRAAIwcWgAMAEkjBkYcAX3GWwpKyrkq48TgAFQg4Bhg0Yzhx-2ZxgHJVcZ6+43GAOieu2NNgRmN6tNnRx3ypmZDX6LZZtNYVUixLZPB4oYonN4fGDjcjzUQlNA1FBEJwQDhKeAANRQNV6ABFSih5HUAMqJNIEpqMCgYrE45z4okk8mU6kwACCdQZGSyzNEW22plx4DxSHc5B41CwhQwwDxdAYzCCtnsUAAFDoIHo0mckNqQlBwkalABKODRapEGDyKAcOAAHlNL2q9phhr0aJ9cQSaAAvJF-UoHiG4EkknBiaSihSfHy6WhA0HajBw5HYXVY-HEzzU3VBTBM1CAHwUNFAA)

Note that I haven't just used `""` as the defaults. The `src` and `alt` props are required on `Image` *for a reason*. I don't use Next.js, but it seems unlikely that `src=""` (in particular) is a valid value, and `alt=""` may be valid, but it's not accessible to users of screen readers and such. But I suspect you just used those in the question as placeholders.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the solution, because I think this is the best solution to this particular problem. 

However, I'd like to note that in my particular use case of using it in MDX, the best solution for me ended up being switching my components file to JSX and not worrying about strict typing.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little messy, but you could have a function that handles checking for the different props you want to watch. Inside this function you could return true if the props are present, and return false if some aren't. Then, you could do conditional rendering depending on the truthy value of said function.

```
const hasProps = propsObject => {
  // if props present, return true
  // otherwise return false
}

// then return something like this
return (
 {hasProps ?
  <Foo
   src={src}
   alt={alt}
   width={width}
   height={height} /> 
   : 
  <Bar />
 }
)
```

OR Maybe you want to be able to check for each prop individually instead of all or none of them. In that case, I'd probably handle that conditionally in the components that's receiving the props. **This is probably how I would handle this situation.**

```
<Foo
 src={src ? src : undefined}
 alt={alt ? alt : undefined}
 width={width ? width : undefined}
 height={height ? height : undefined} />

// Handle receiving props in Foo
function Foo(props) {
 const [width, setWidth] = useState(props.width)
 ...
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the underlying component unfortunately. It's the built in Next `<Image>` component.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solutions. It looks a little bulky and ugly, but it can solve your problem.

```
const src = undefined;
const alt = 1;
const width = 100;
const height = undefined;

const props = {
    ...(src && { src }),
    ...(alt && { alt }),
    ...(width && { width }),
    ...(height && { height }),
}; # <-- Here will be only "alt" and "width"

return (<Image {...props}/>);
```